# Error with uploading site that uses codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

After uploading my site to a hosting, it shows the following error:

> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/home/u630543546/public_html/mikenpina/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.3/pear') in
>   /home/u630543546/public_html/mikenpina/system/core/Exceptions.php on
>   line 216
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/home/u630543546/public_html/mikenpina/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.3/pear') in
>   /home/u630543546/public_html/mikenpina/system/core/Exceptions.php on
>   line 216

What could be the cause of this? I've been tracing the error since yesterday but can't seem to find it. I used CodeIgniter 2.2.0 and the latest stable bootstrap.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: try removing : from this and include the correct path, which should be probably  include_path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].('/opt/php-5.3/pear') in system/core/Exceptions.php file

Comment: It's telling you that the `error_php.php` file can't be opened, this could be a permission issue, or the file is simply not there. The path seems reasonable being that the `Exceptions.php` file is being loaded. Try `is_readable` and `file_exists` on that bad path. @noob the `:` is a path separator, pretty normal to have the working directory and the path to pear in the include path.

Comment: thanks for that but what is '.' doing there before : (path separator) ?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas where should I exactly place/use 'is_readable' and 'file_exists'? In what file in CodeIgniter? Sorry I really don't know.

Comment: at the top of the `Exception.php` file would suffice since you know for a fact that file is loading since it's where your error comes from

Comment: @noob that `.` means current directory... that's necessary for relative paths to work

Comment: well if it means the current directory will we be looking at mikenpina/system/core/Exceptions.php/opt/php-5.3/pear ??

Comment: @SteveBuzonas really sorry about this, but what should I exactly put at the top of the Exception.php?

Comment: `var_dump(file_exists('/home/u630543546/public_html/mikenpina/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php'), is_readable('/home/u630543546/public_html/mikenpina/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php'));`

Comment: those two functions return booleans, so it's simpler to just `var_dump` them to get the result, and you want to pass the path of the file it says it cannot open to see if you can determine why it can't open it, those would be two of the more common scenarios

Comment: They returned bool(false), bool(false). Should I delete something?

Comment: Please help me on this pleasee pleasee thanks!! Really urgent for thesis! T_T

Comment: So that means your file isn't at the path it expects it to be at. How do you upload your application? Do you have ssh access?